# Comparing the position of 1's is matched in the strings in r

Tags: r, string

Suppose I am reading a .csv file from R whose columns contain strings of 0s and 1s. Suppose I need to compare the position of 1's and if matched then count as 1 per match and put that count in the third column.

**Illustration**:

```
dput(head(string_data))
structure(list(v_1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"0,0,0,1", "0,0,1,0", "0,1,0,0", "1,1,0,0"), class = "factor"), 
    v_2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "1,0,1,0"), class = "factor"), v_3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "0,0,0,1", "0,0,1,0", "1,0,0,0"
    ), class = "factor"), v_4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "0,0,0,1"), class = "factor"), v_5 = structure(c(1L, 
    5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0,0,0,0,0", "0,0,0,1,0", 
    "0,0,1,0,0", "1,0,1,1,0"), class = "factor"), v_6 = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "1,0,1,1,0"), class = "factor"), 
    v_7 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
    "0,0,0,0", "0,0,0,1", "0,1,0,0", "1,0,0,0"), class = "factor"), 
    v_8 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
    "1,0,0,0"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("v_1", "v_2", 
"v_3", "v_4", "v_5", "v_6", "v_7", "v_8"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Above I have pasted `dput` of head data.

I need to compare the position of 1's in (2*i-1) column with (2*i)th column (i =1,2,...,8) and put that in a third column. as number of matches.

e.g.

Suppose I have a string 0,0,1,1 in first column and 0,1,1,1 in second column then in the third column it should return   2.

Can anyone please help me out with this one.

**EDIT**

The counting in the third column should be based on the number of 1's in the second column string. In above e.g. second column string is 0,1,1,1 which implies it the count can very from 0 to 3.

Comment: Is it too vague question? or difficult one?

Comment: Please provide the expected output for your example.

Answer (score 0):

This couple of functions might be helpful as a starter:

```
# Compares two strings and computes number of '1's at matching positions
f <- function(s1, s2) {
    if (s1=='' || s2=='') return(0)
    m <- do.call(cbind,strsplit(c(s1,s2),','))
    m2 <- rowMeans(m=="1")
    sum(m2==1.0)
}

# Calls `f()` for every row of two columns i and j from a data set d and returns a vector 
# that could be used as a new column
f.cols <- function(d,i,j) {
    c1 <- as.character(d[,i])
    c2 <- as.character(d[,j])
    unname(mapply(f,c1,c2))
}
```

Example of use:

```
d$out <- f.cols(d,1,2)
```